# Switching Parallel Solar Cells

Tags: solar-cell, mppt

I have a proposed solar system setup where sometimes one set of panels will be covered. The system has control over when the panel is covered or not. I'm thinking of ways to isolate the covered cells from the parallel set up - is this a reasonable way to go about things? Could/should I just replace it with a diode (and will that work better)?

[image]
(ignore placeholder resistor values)

Comment: simulation at https://tinyurl.com/2hagy6np

Comment: do they need to be isolated?

Comment: I'm assuming that having them not be isolated when they're covered would mean that the overall system becomes less efficient in some way (because current flows back through the other), but it's been a while since I last used solar

Comment: actually I previously thought that too, but someone corrected me that solar panels are really big diodes, and current can't flow the wrong way

Comment: I also thought that they were diodes, but a lot of sources on the internet talk about blocking diodes as a common thing in solar, so it made me wonder - maybe the breakdown voltage isnt very high?